# Symfony2: How do I clear all of Symfony's (and all 3rd party plugins) cache in 1 command?

Tags: symfony

so I've been testing Doctrine queries and other Symfony code and I have to run several commands just to clear Doctrine/Symfony caches. I was searching for the net and came across another command to clear Assetic assets/etc.

From what I've read

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

will only clear Symfony cache. it won't include Doctrine and perhaps more.

I know I can create a bash script to clear all my caches but this obviously means I know all the "clear cache" commands. I only found out about the Assetic clear cache/assets by accident. What about those I don't know?

So is there 1 "clear cache" command that can do it for me? This will have to include Symfony/Doctrine/Assetic/Twig and whatever plugins I have installed.

Thanks a lot

Comment: rm -r var/cache will do the trick.  Everything ends up under the cache directory.  But I think you may be misreading the documentation.  Yes, doctrine does provide commands specifically for it's cache but the symfony cache:clear one is the only one I have ever used and doctrine updates just fine.  Try it.

Comment: not all caches are written to disk, for example, if you use redis.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is highly dependent on the developer of the bundle that uses the cache. Not even doctrine, that comes with the standard version of symfony has its cache clear command integrated. But what you can do is extend the default symfony command with a listener that runs all the cache clear command you want like this:

```
<?php
namespace DefaultBundle\Event\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\CacheClearer\CacheClearerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class CacheClearListener implements CacheClearerInterface
{
    private $environment;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    private static function getCommands()
    {
        return array(
            'php ./app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata --no-debug --flush',
            'php ./app/console doctrine:cache:clear-query --no-debug --flush',
            'php ./app/console doctrine:cache:clear-result --no-debug --flush'
        );
    }

    public function clear($cacheDir)
    {
        $output = new ConsoleOutput();
        $output->writeln('');
        $output->writeln('<info>Clearing Doctrine cache</info>');

        foreach (self::getCommands() as $command) {
            $command .= ' --env='.$this->environment;
            $success = $this->executeCommand($command, $output);

            if (!$success) {
                $output->writeln(sprintf('<info>An error occurs when running: %s!</info>', $command));
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param string        $command
     * @param ConsoleOutput $output
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function executeCommand($command, ConsoleOutput $output)
    {
        $p = new Process($command);
        $p->setTimeout(null);
        $p->run(
            function ($type, $data) use ($output) {
                $output->write($data, false, OutputInterface::OUTPUT_RAW);
            }
        );
        if (!$p->isSuccessful()) {
            return false;
        }
        $output->writeln('');

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param Kernel $kernel
     */
    public function setKernel(Kernel $kernel)
    {
        $this->environment = $kernel->getEnvironment();
    }
}
```

Register the listener like this:

```
<service id="cache_clear_listener" class="DefaultBundle\Event\Listener\CacheClearListener">
    <call method="setKernel">
        <argument type="service" id="kernel"/>
    </call>
    <tag name="kernel.cache_clearer"  priority="254" />
</service>
```

And that is all. Now all you need to do is keep adding your new cache clear command to the getCommands() method. In order to find this commands you can run something like

```
php app/console | grep cache
```

to see all available commands that contain the word "cache" in them

After your listener is set, every time you run php app/console cache:clear it will trigger all the command that you listed in the getCommands() method of your listener.

Hope this helps,
Alexandru